# Why is copying with {ctrl down}c{ctrl up} more secure than ^c?

Tags: security, autohotkey

The  [AutoHotkey Beginner Tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) includes the following [sample script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s24) to demonstrate hotkeys.

```
^b::
   send, {ctrl down}c{ctrl up}             ; Copies the selected text. ^c could be used as well, but this method is more secure.
   SendInput, [b]{ctrl down}v{ctrl up}[/b]
Return
```

The code comments suggest that `{ctrl down}c{ctrl up}` is a more secure way of copying text than `^c`. However, the tutorial never elaborates on *why* the latter method is less secure.

**Why is copying text with `{ctrl down}c{ctrl up}` considered more secure than using `^c`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Secure" in the sense they mean, is that the command is more likely to succeed in the majority of applications the command is being sent to.

First, examine the send type (SendInput, SendDirect, SendPlay, etc) and their various quirks.

When you use a Send method of any type it is not actually pressing your keyboard keys - it is sending a control message to the active window (hence the need for different send methods, sometimes).

Next, it's really all about timing, assuming the messages are getting through.

If you were to use `{ctrl down}your-stuff{ctrl up}` you can control the timing of each individually, such as:

```
Send {ctrl down}
Sleep 200
Send c
Sleep 200
Send {ctrl up}
```

This sometimes becomes necessary if the system is not accepting your `^c`-type command - and it's almost always due to timing or buffering issues with the sent message. I get away with `^c`-type messages most of the time, when working in windowed applications. However, if you are working in a DirectX application (like a game), having explicit timing for key-down and key-up events is crucial.

Comment: Would a more accurate description be "more reliable" instead of "more secure"?